# User excessively using distracting formatting and hyperbolic language

Tags: discussion, flags, comments

I stumbled across a user who has made a habit of using distracting formatting and hyperbolic language in their comments (hyperbolic = aggressively criticizing the OP beyond what is warranted).  A couple examples:

> Maybe because adding an **entire new dependency** to do the job of a single-line function is fragile over-kill? You know. *Just sayin'*.
>
> **This should probably have been the accepted answer.** Thanks nonetheless for your cogent explanation, Sir Sebastian.
>
> **Yeah**. Your last go at it wins the day. In the ideal world, this answer would be slightly rewritten to emphasize the winning regex. Nonetheless, this should be relentlessly upvoted. *Viva la bestest answer!*

First, is there an appropriate general flag reason for comments like this?  To me, the first seems rude, the second seems too chatty, but the third is a legitimate comment wrapped with noise.  It feels like I'm treating this on a case by case basis for an obvious problem.

Second, how do I properly alert moderation so they can talk to the user and end their bad habit?

Comment: the comments of the revisions are just funny http://stackoverflow.com/users/2809027/cecil-curry?tab=activity

Comment: **Frankly**...I'd just *let it be*.

Comment: On an unimportant question, sure, but some of these are dumped on high view questions, eg 10k, 40k, 100k.  I don't want a stack overflow where I search for an answer only to have the signal drowned out by attention seeking.

Comment: I saw this in my RSS feed, and was elated!  Then I realized it wasn't about me.  If using *distracting formatting* and **hyperbolic language** in comments is wrong, ***then I don't wanna be right!*** Also, calm thy heaving breast.  This is a complete non-issue.  If you want to make the site better, go fix all the awful, poorly formatted questions and answers first.

Comment: Can I get someone to give a *serious response* instead of *ridicule* on this?  I can totally give **leeway for fun and games**, but there comes times when behavior gets legitimately problemantic; the couple flags I raised were already marked as helpful and were actioned.  I'm not sure what the venue to *ask nicely* is without either going off topic and potentially confrontation in comment threads, or raising individual flags on the dozen other comments that are **pure noise for tens of thousands of people**.

Comment: *I search for an answer only to have the signal drowned out by attention seeking.* - Comments aren't searchable, otherwise you'd be getting them in your search results now from folks putting useful info there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I sympathize, but this is kind of like asking the guy you see in the cafeteria every other day, who works in a different department, if he could please speak more quietly when he's chatting in line, because he doesn't realize he's yelling loud enough for everyone to hear every word. Even if he reins it in for a day or two, he's not actually conscious of his behavior being anything other than completely normal. "Fixing" it means him agreeing that he's doing something wrong, and then somebody slapping him every time he does it: not a realistic proposal on Stack Overflow. It's the task of a parent, not a peer.

There's a user who sometimes answers in my home tags who's given to this same sort of excess, though more in answers than comments, and I believe that the best I can do is roll my eyes and avoid him. (I will also edit out the most egregiously indefensible uses of formatting, when I can stomach editing the post at all.)

For these comments, unfortunately I think you are limited to flagging the worst of the worst -- the second two you presented certainly seem to have no redeeming content -- and living with the rest.

Comment: "The one true answer: *it has emerged*." A verifiable vichyssoise of verbiage, in other words, not to everyone's taste.

Answer (score 3):

Seems lots of individual flags are the preferred solution.

I just flagged the harmful comments.  2 rude or offensive, 4 too chatty, all helpful and actioned.  Rest of user's comments either had appropriate usage, had redeeming value, or weren't intrusive enough to merit flagging.

It would be *nice* to see us discourage the **exuberant use of bold**, but as long as bold doesn't become the next `backticks as formatting` trend flags should be able to continue keeping out the egregious instances.  **God bless StackOverflow.**